# Receiving UDP data in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to receive UDP data broadcast by PlayCap to network address 192.168.103.255 port 3000 in Java, but I'm having trouble setting things up. Here's what I have:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.103.255", 3000);
socket.bind(address);
```

I'm getting "java.net.SocketException: already bound" from the bind call. I'm pretty inexperienced with networking, so I may be doing something way wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: already bound
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at runner.main(runner.java:16)
```

Comment: A service (maybe an older version of your program) is already listening on port 3000. Eithor Terminate that process or find a new port.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I dont want to revive and old thread but i don't think the answer to this question is correct. I faced the same issue when i used the similar code to create a DatagramSocket.

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 5566));
```

This results in a SocketException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: already bound
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:376)
at testapplication.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:25)
```

Java Result: 1

Not because there is another process occupying the same port but i have created an already **BOUND** datagram socket when i use the default constructor.

```
new DatagramSocket()
```

According to [javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket()):

> DatagramSocket()
>   Constructs a datagram socket and **binds it** to any available port on the
>   local host machine.

So the reason for the exception is you are trying to bind an already bound socket. To make it work you need to create an unbond socket with below constructor

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.103.255", 3000);
socket.bind(address);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: very helpfull `DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);` thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do 
 **netstat -a -o -n**
 and from this you can find that either this port is already bind or not(even from this you can get all the bound ports).If yes , then try any other port :)

Comment: I ran that command, but the port isn't listed (neither the IP address 192.168.103.255 nor port 3000 is listed anywhere). Also, I can't use another port since I'm trying to receive data that is being broadcast from PlayCap (http://www.signal11.us/oss/playcap/) on my local machine, and it doesn't seem like I can specify which port to broadcast on.

Comment: is data coming from your local machine? Have you tried it by 
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 3000); or InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 3000);

Comment: 192.168.103.255 is not my IP address. That's the destination address of the data, according to WireShark. Do I need to do any port forwarding or disabling Windows firewall? Yes, I had tried your suggestions and get the same "already bound" error.

Comment: ok then check your firewall setting.Which OS you are using? For somtime , close your firewall and then check ..

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, and I'm programming in Eclipse Juno. I just tried turning off WIndows firewall, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably **your application is running twice**. Or you might be executing the same code twice. Even the same application may fail when binding twice.

Happens a lot for beginners that they didn't shut down their previous attempt (happened to me, too), and then their port is already in use. Make sure to add proper exception handling, e.g. by popping up a message "Port already in use."

Note that for *listening* you usually will bind a **port only**, without an explicit address (you might need to use "0.0.0.0" for this). Then you can receive both broadcast and unicast.

The code I use for listening to broadcasts is simply:

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port))
```

Note that I'm not binding to a particular address, but only to a port.

Comment: I just tried using "0.0.0.0" and rebooted my machine and got the "already bound" error both times. According to WireShark, 192.168.103.255 is the destination address of the data. The person who supplied me with the data indicated that this address is where the data is broadcast (this is not my IP address). Am I going about receiving this data correctly?

Comment: No need to reboot. Use your system utilities (e.g. `netstat`) to see which process is listening on the port. Does a different port work? If you get the same error for all ports, it is a policy thing (windows firewall etc.) Or your application is binding twice, and the second time fails.

Comment: I ran netstat, and the address and port aren't listed anywhere. I tried different ports, and I can't seem to get any port to bind. Every address/port I try gives me the same "already bound" error. I tried turning off Windows firewall, but that didn't help. I don't think I'm binding twice, since my application is literally just the code I listed in my original post (inside a try-catch block, of course). I also inserted the code you listed in your post, but still get "already bound" for any port I try! This is so frustrating!

Comment: Which java version do you use? Is it maybe sandboxed or something like that? Can you update the question with a full stacktrace?

Comment: My Java version is "1.7.0_09-b05". How would I know if it is sandboxed? I added the stacktrace, but unfortunately I don't think it's going to be very helpful.

Comment: Java applets for example usually run sandboxed. A java applet on a web page will not be allowed to listen for UDP broadcasts on your local network, I guess - at least it should not be allowed to do so. It should however also give a different exception. Maybe try a minimal code example that you can completely put into your question next. And *do* try a different programming language. If it is a firewall/system policy thing, it should affect other languages as well. If you cannot bind in C either, it's not Javas fault.

Answer (score 0):

Check the port 3000 it may be already used by another application. Try using a different port.